# Angular Disable Input Based on Checkbox

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to make an html checkbox control whether a date input is disabled or not.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="noDates">Disable Date: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="noDate" >
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

How would I disable to the date selector though the checkbox. I have tried to add the attribute `disabled="noDate"`, `[disabled]="noDate"`, and  `[attr.disabled]="noDate"` but none have worked

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go. You can use `disabled` property on input. Just add `standalone: true` options. Details at [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="noDates">Disable Date: </label>
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="noDate"
  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" [disabled]="noDate"/>
  </div>
</form>
```